# Correct way to render a mobile first website on a desktop

Tags: css

I am trying to render a mobile first website on a desktop and would like to limit the viewport to let say 500px aligned in the middle.

While this part is easy, there are some other complexities also.

- The top bar and bottom bar which have position as fixed are fixed relative to viewport so they are taking the width of the viewport
- The side navigation bar are opening from the far left corner.

Fixing these problems individually is one solution, but i am wondering if there is a more standard way to restrict the size of the entire viewport ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why can’t you give desktop users a proper desktop experience? I hate having to browse a mobile-style website on a desktop! (And “mobile-first” implies “desktop-second”, not “mobile-only” which is what you’re describing)

Comment: If this is for dev/preview/prototyping purposes, then use your browser’s mobile emulation mode rather than breaking desktop browsing.

Comment: @Dai well there are business requirements which are forcing me to not invest much time to build a responsive experience, and this is what is trending right now, look at the new facebook, instagram is also just tablet.